# How to increase Start Timeout for Websphere 8.5.5 In Intellij , I know in Eclipse we can just double click on server?

Tags: eclipse, intellij-idea, websphere, websphere-8, intellij-plugin

We can Increase the server start Timeout of Websphere 8.5.5 in eclipse by double clicking on Websphere server and in Timeout section set the seconds , but how to do it in Intellij , I could not find any answer online

EDIT : One Solution suggested to me was to add  {profile}/bin/startServer.bat server1 -timeout 8000   or whatever number in Startup/Connection -> Startup Script Section in Intellij , I moved back to Eclipse , So I did not verify it completely

Comment: What error do you get in IntelliJ IDEA? Why do you need to increase it?

Comment: It gives a timeout alarm error , in eclipse if I increase the start timeout it works ok

Comment: Please post the full error or file an issue at https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/newIssue?project=IDEA.

Answer (score 0):

You can modify the timeout values in the profile. `${PROFILE_HOME}/config/cells/${CELL}/nodes/${NODE}/servers/${SERVER}/server.xml`

Even if you add the server to Eclipse or IntelliJ, you have to choose the profile.

Just see if there is a workspace reference of the above server.xml file.

If it's there, modify the value in that.

Comment: Where to add the timeout in server.xml there are lots of things in it

Comment: One easy way, try that in Eclipse and see the value added by Eclipse. Then use the same in server.xml file that is loaded via IntelliJ